# How to keep SwiftUI Navigation Swipe Back gesture, when NavigationStack has a padding?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationstack

I'm using **SwiftUI**'s `NavigationStack`. **When `NavigationStack` has a `.padding()`, the swipe back gesture no longer works.** My best guess is that the gesture has to be triggered from the edge of the screen. And with padding, it cannot trigger.

```
NavigationStack {
    List(1..<50) { i in
        NavigationLink(value: i) {
            Label("Row \(i)", systemImage: "\(i).circle")
        }
    }
    .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { i in
        Text("Detail \(i)")
    }
    .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
}
.padding()
```

For example, like the image below, you can no longer swipe back from detail view.
**How could I keep the swipe back gesture, while having a `.padding` on a `NavigationStack`?**

[image]

Comment: Why use a padding on the `NavigationStack`? Maybe you can achieve your expectation using a different way.

Comment: @Timmy Sadly, the NavigationView is SubView of the app to fit the overall look. I need to figure out a way to extend the gesture area of the navigation to include the padding area.